# how to use CMUsphinx with ARM microcontrollers?

Tags: arm, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I just searched about an open-source library to use of my project to build a voice controlled robot and found CMUsphinx. but my robot will build on ARM based microcontroller and I have not Linux or Windows on it. Is it possible to use CMUsphinx on ARM based microcontrollers? How can I do it?
Is there any better options instead of using CMUsphinx on ARM uControllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use a variant of CMUSphinx, known as PocketSphinx, on ARM devices. Most resources focus on Raspberry Pi, as it's a very popular ARM target.

The instructions for installing on a Raspberry Pi are here:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2016/06/should-you-select-raspberry-pi-3-or-raspberry-pi-b-for-cmusphinx/

There's a voice assistant for Raspberry Pi that uses CMUSphinx:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2014/04/jasper-personal-assistant-for-raspberry-pi/comment-page-1/

And, there's a recent blog post about running on the Raspberry Pi here:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2016/06/should-you-select-raspberry-pi-3-or-raspberry-pi-b-for-cmusphinx/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use CMUsphinx on ARM based microcontrollers?

No, it's not possible to use CMUSphinx on microcontrollers.

> but my robot will build on ARM based microcontroller

Consider using more powerful CPU, it will help you with other tasks like navigation or network sync as well.

Comment: It's not possible to use CMUsphinx to build something like this:
http://www.mikroe.com/click/speakup/

So, what alternative way you know to doing it?

Comment: This is simple dynamic time warping implementation with prerecorded words. It works only for a single speaker and not very useful for real practical things. I recommend more powerful CPU since demands of the users are already higher than you can have with microcontroller

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, But I want to build a simple voice controlled toy that when baby calls it with some commands (Go, Come , etc) does related action, and maybe answer to some questions like "what's your name?".
So the costs is very important for me and I like to build it as cheap as it could be and although as usable as it should.

What's your opinion about this commercial project?

Comment: There are many projects for really small-footprint recognition like  https://github.com/arjo129/uSpeech, https://github.com/going-digital/Talkie you need to research a bit. Ideally you want some feature extraction + dynamic time warping implementation. As for answering the questions, it's another problem to have synthesis.